# How to find all directories named DOG and renaming it to CAT using a batch file

Tags: cmd, file-rename, batch-rename

In a batch file, I would like to find all the directories under C:\Temp that are literally named `DOG`.  I would then like to loop through the returned results and rename the directories from `DOG` to `CAT`.  The following code I found lists the directories that are named `DOG`, however, I am unsure how to manipulate the returned results to rename the directory from `DOG` to `CAT`.

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /b /s /a:d "C:\Temp\DOG"') do echo Found %%G
```

My failed attempt

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /b /s /a:d "c:\temp\DOG"') do (
  set "source=%%G"
  echo BEFORE
  echo source %source%
  echo.
  set target=%source:\DOG =\CAT%
  echo AFTER
  echo source %source%
  echo target %target%
  ren %source% %target%
)
```

Comment: [DOS is not cmd](https://superuser.com/q/451432/241386). There's no `for /f` in DOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
for /d /r "c:\temp" %%a in (*) do if /i "%%~nxa"=="DOG" ren "%%a" "CAT"
```